# Tensorflow, proper way to define a loss function with element-wise operations

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I have a batch of **n** training examples. Each training example yields me with a vector **a** (of length k) and a vector **c** (also of length k).

In tensorflow my output is **p**.

I would like to define the following loss function:

\sum_(i = 0)^(i=n) c_i ( (a_i - p)^2 )

I have read about various tf operations available to me but cannot seem to find out a proper implementation for this. I tried to use tf.tile to replicate p into a k-length tensor and do a tf.subtract, but this seems excessive.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the shape of **p**? TensorFlow natively supports subtraction of tensors with different shapes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])

x_1 = a - tf.Variable([1, 1, 1])
x_2 = a - tf.Variable([1])
x_3 = a - tf.Variable(1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x_1))  # [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]]
    print(sess.run(x_2))  # [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]]
    print(sess.run(x_3))  # [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]]
```

You can define your loss function as follows:

```
a = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
c = tf.Variable([[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]])

p = tf.Variable(1)

loss_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(c, tf.pow(tf.subtract(a, p), 2)), axis=1))  # 112
loss_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(c * (a-p)**2, axis=1))  # 112
```

Comment: Awesome, wow I am oblivious. Sorry that my tensorflow experience is somewhat lacking. My value of p is just [p], simply some scalar.  Any idea how I would go about constructing the rest of the loss function? Would it be something along the lines of

tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(c, tf.reduce_sum((x_3)**2))

Comment: Your code snippet would work, but I don't think it's what you wanted if I interpreted the formula in your question correctly. I edited my answer and included the loss function that I think you want. (For each batch element: Subtract scalar _p_ from each element in vector _a_; square the resulting vector element wise; multiply the resulting vector element wise with vector _c_ and calculate the sum of all its elements (so basically dot product); Finally, take the mean of this value of all batch elements)